# Getting div contet from Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used this query to make the ajax call

```
$j.ajax({
    url: durl,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'html',
    complete: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
        var aa = $j(data).filter('#outputMessage').text();
        console.log(aa);
    }
});
```

the response text printed on the console has

```
<div id ="outputMessage">
    Could not process transactions. 
</div>
```

i used both filter and find which prints empty string on the console. Am i doing something wrong here . How can i get the div content message from the ajax response

Comment: Have you tried `$j(data.responseText).find('#outputMessage').text()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lot of things , I finally figured it out by using like this

```
$j(data.responseText).filter('#outputMessage').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

As `data.responseText` has the required content.

You need to use

```
$j(data.responseText).find('#outputMessage').text()
```

instead of

```
$j(data).find('#outputMessage').text()
```

Comment: And why wouldn't the data be in just `data` ?

Comment: Why do you have to use `data.responseText`, what difference does it make, the returned content should be available in just `data`.

Comment: @adeneo, As OP is using `complete` callback function and `data` here will represent `jqXHR` object(as you already know) thus he needs to use `data.responseText` which is the actual content which ajax is requesting

Comment: @satpal i tried your suggestion i'm getting an empty message

Comment: i also tried like this $j(data).html() and getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like below ?

```
var aa = $j(data.responseText).html();
console.log(aa);
```

Comment: getting an empty message